# JavaFX Media can't read mp3 streams?

Tags: java, streaming, mp3, javafx-2

I am trying to create a simple streaming mp3 server and client. I have a server that works with all clients I can find. I next tried to create a streaming client that uses javafx Media, essentially this:

```
    new JFXPanel();
    final Media media = new Media(url);
    final MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    player.setOnPlaying(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { System.out.println("Running"); }
    });
    player.play();
```

This works when URL is a file:///, but not when the URL is pointed to my streaming server. Nor does it work when pointing to http://lyd.nrk.no/nrk_radio_mp3_mp3_h. Manually spooling the data to disk with curl and then playing it from file works fine.

Java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

Platform is Debian Linux with pulseaudio.

Does anybody know if this is supposed to work?

EDIT:

Not working means, it reads some data from the network and then seems to stop. It does not print "Running."

Comment: Set an onError handler and see if there was an error.

Comment: JavaFX 2.2 supports [HTTP live streaming](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming).  Detailed technical specs of [supported media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) are listed.

Comment: Is libavformat53 installed as per the [JavaFX linux system requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/system_requirements_2-2-3/jfxpub-system_requirements_2-2-3.htm).